# Sourcing the correct N-Channel MOSFET

Tags: nmos

I'm new to using MOSFETs and I need to source one for a personal project of mine. I'm using an N-Channel FET to pull down a 12v (5mA) logic/signal line from logic level (3.3v).

I've used an [FQP30N06L](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/FQP30N06L.pdf) successfully, but I'm looking to move to an SMD part, specifically the BSS138K from ON Semi.

[Looking at the DS](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/BSS138K-1305178.pdf), I see that the RDS(ON), and that a Vgs of 2.5v with an Id of 50mA produces about 2ohms of resistance. This leads me to assume that this MOSFET would be suitable for my use case. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Looks okay to me given what little you write. (I've no idea how fast you intend operating it. That might matter. But it's not mentioned, so it must not matter.)

Comment: @jonk - It really doesn't matter. I need response within a couple milliseconds and the gate is going to stay pulled up for seconds at a time, and will not be pulsed. I simply need to signal another device that a specific condition has been met.

Comment: I like AOD508, AOD510, AOD514,Very low Rds (in the milliohms, 0.0065 ohm), turns on with 5V from microprocessor (such as Arduino) or from 74HC595 even.  Easy to work with TO252 package.

Comment: The only problem is that I'm using a PIC24FJ MCU and I only have a few 5v tolerant  pins, which is why I'm trying to work with 3.3v.